# Send Data from UIViewController to UIView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, segue, popupwindow

Iam trying to send data from a UIViewController to a UIView. I have looked everywhere but none seem to work correctly. As shown below, I am trying to send popup.priceLabel.text and popup.notificationLabel.text from a UIViewcontroller to UIView when the user selects a particular row. I tried to use segue's, protocols and other methods but nothing seems to work. Below is what I am trying to accomplish(I know its incorrect but just to illustrate intent):

```
//UIViewController

class CouponsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("selected = \(indexPath.row)")
    let popup = PopUpWindow()
    popup.priceLabel.text = "100.00"
    popup.notificationLabel.text = "Store"
    handleShowPopUp()
}

@objc func handleShowPopUp() {
    popUpWindow.showSuccessMessage = success
    success = !success
    popUpWindow.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    popUpWindow.alpha = 0
}
}
```

```
//UIView

class PopUpWindow: UIView {
    var delegate: PopUpDelegate?

    var showSuccessMessage: Bool? {
        didSet {
            guard showSuccessMessage != nil else { return }
            priceLabel.text = ""
            notificationLabel.text = ""
            priceLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 147/255, green: 227/255, blue: 105/255, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example, you’re setting showSuccessMessage before showing the view. When that happens, your didSet property observer is setting the label text to an empty String before the view is scaled up.

Comment: Thanks-So do I need like a delay or place the code in a different location? WHat's shown works but its not set in time is that what you're saying?

Comment: You need to set showSuccessMessage before you set the text of your two labels.

Comment: Iam sorry I’m not sure if I’m misunderstanding the suggestion: do you mean to set the values in showSuccessMessage to something instead of “”? If so, I tried that and it still doesn’t update the value I had set in the table view function

Comment: If you could show an example, it would be greatly appreciated I've tried different things but nothing has worked

Comment: You should create one instance of a PopUpView and then you can set value of texts and present it. But I really don't understand why you changed priceLabel's text etc. in showSuccessMessage  didSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you tried your segue inside `didSelectRowAt()` method but, it will not work because you are trying to pass data without initializing `priceLabel` `notificationLabel` so there is another way to accomplish it. You need create a variable in your `popupView` for your price and notification.

```
var price: String = ""
```

Inside your `didSelectRowAt()` method what you need to do is `popup.price = "100.0"`. Then inside the popup's `viewDidLoad()` method you need to do following.

```
priceLabel.text = price
```